# How to filter an array by one condition without a re-renderer?

Tags: reactjs

How to filter an array by one condition without a re-renderer?

I want to display the button if the result of the check returns true, but the point is that true or false is returned on each iteration, how can I return true or false only once?

```
  const [checkStatus, setCheckStatus] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const statusChecker = () => {
    const result = items.map(
      item =>
        item.status !== 'red' && item.status === 'yellow',
    );
    const [check] = result;
    if (check) setCheckStatus(check);
  };

return (
 {checkStatus && (
  <Button>Click me</Button>
 )}
)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `items.find`? It would return the first object that matches the predicate, or `undefined` if none match.

Comment: how `statusChecker` is called?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using `useMemo`, if you not pass any dependencies at first render, it just calls once and returns result you needed, and you can use `filter` higher-order function to find which item is `item.status === "yellow"`

```
const checkStatus = useMemo(() => {
  return items.filter(
    item => item.status !== "red" && item.status === "yellow"
  );
}, []);
```

if you pass a dependence `items`, it will be called when items change, like this:

```
const checkStatus = useMemo(() => {
  return items.filter(
    item => item.status !== "red" && item.status === "yellow"
  );
}, [items]);
```